# How do I merge/delete overlapping edges/faces on a mesh?

Tags: mesh, unreal-engine

I've just started using Blender to UV unwrap some of the buildings and roads I'm importing into Unreal Engine. My goal is to build replicas of multiple cities/areas and I will need proper textures for these structures. The buildings have worked beautifully but the road meshes unfortunately didn't turn out the same.

The issue lies within the fact that each of the edges/faces overlap one another and creates a weird "flashing" effect in my world. I would like to eliminate this effect but I don't know how to stop the meshing from overlapping from one another.

File I'm using (.blend):
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6MSebnmg

[image: Strange Mesh overlap in Unreal Engine]

[image: Same overlapping in Blender]

Comment: If all these faces are part of 1 object, you need to separate overlapping sections into their own objects so you can use a Boolean modifier. Select any face and hit `CTRL+PLUS` until the face count stops ascending. Hit the `P` key to make it's own object. Exit Edit Mode. Select the more complicated object. Edit Mode again. Select a face that was previously overlapping. Repeat what we just did. Eventually you will (probably) have objects that do not self-intersect. In Object mode, give one of these a Boolean modifier set to "Union" choose an overlapping object as the input...

Comment: ...If that worked, Apply the modifier and delete the input object. IF THAT DID NOT WORK, it might be because the Boolean modifier requires both objects to enclose a volume (they cannot be flat faces). In fact, I think this is true. You can extrude all the faces a fixed distance as the very first step and do all this again; you can also extrude one object's faces at a time.

Comment: I would also propose an experiment: Before doing anything, and assuming the streets are one self-intersecting object: Select all the faces and extrude them. Duplicate the object. Put a Boolean modifier on one of them and feed it the other using "Union". I doubt this would work but it would be amazing if it did.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, the `CTRL+PLUS` shortcut doesn't seem to affect the face count. At least, I don't where where the counter should display (I assume at the bottom of the screen). The Separation by Loose Parts worked and I ended up with 600 individual faces but the modifier didn't seem to work for some reason. I did try the Extrude and copy/paste as you had mentioned but it didn't seem to work either. If possible, do you mind uploading a really short video on your steps? I can give you the .fbx file I'm using

Comment: Here is the .fbx file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rcnLGHkLND6MiCv0alAvtbX_nVZk1Ecp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need a keyboard with a "numpad" to use Blender most effectively. The shortcuts are on the area to the right where the number keys are arranged 789,456,123,0. You can turn on the option to simulate the numpad with the topmost keys for your keyboard in Preferences if you don't have one. Not all shortcuts will be available though.

Comment: Don't send FBX files, Google is blocking it. Send the .blend instead. If it is too big, Unpack external data first. File --> External Data --> Unpack All into Files --> Remove Pack. Use blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com
to attach your file to this stack exchange posting (you will need to scroll down on that page, copy-paste the URL for this posting, agree to the terms, and hit the button to do it)

Comment: Ok it's posted. I will leave the link in the original post of this thread. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Yikes, dude, the faces for these streets don't even "go all the way through", each piece is only like 2 triangle faces. I think you just need to extrude a plane over the streets, snapping to the vertices you want. You can do this very quickly in Edit mode by switching between Vertex and Edge mode by tapping the top "1" and "2" keys, respectively. Don't forget that you can also make custom transform orientations by being in Normal orientation with an edge or face selected and clicking the "+" icon in the orientation drop-down.